# Possible bug in bookdown when compiling to PDF. Images get cut by the margins

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

When I compile my Bookdown books for pdf output I get figures cut by the left and right margins. This does not happen if I generate them with `ggsave()` myself and then add them with `knitter::include_graphics()`.

````
    ---
    output:
      pdf_document: default
      html_document: default
    ---

    # Example
    ```{r example, message=FALSE}
    require(tidyverse)
    ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width))+geom_point()
    ```
````

I execute `bookdown::render("index.Rmd", output_format=pdf_book(keep_tex=TRUE))

I get this image as output (in main_files/figure-latex)

[image: Image I get, it is cut by the margins]

Is this a bug or is it just me? How can I solve it? I do not like very much the idea of `ggsave()` + `knitr::include_image()`, but it is the only workaround I got so far.

### Extra information about my system

```
> xfun::session_info('bookdown')
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: openSUSE Leap 15.1, RStudio 1.2.5019

Locale:
  LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8       
  LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8   
  LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
  LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3 bookdown_0.17   digest_0.6.18   evaluate_0.14   glue_1.3.1     
  graphics_3.6.2  grDevices_3.6.2 highr_0.3       htmltools_0.4.0 jsonlite_1.6   
  knitr_1.28      magrittr_1.5    markdown_1.1    methods_3.6.2   mime_0.8       
  Rcpp_1.0.3      rlang_0.4.4     rmarkdown_2.1   stats_3.6.2     stringi_1.2.4  
  stringr_1.4.0   tinytex_0.18    tools_3.6.2     utils_3.6.2     xfun_0.8       
  yaml_2.2.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the `fig_crop` argument on the help page `?rmarkdown::pdf_document`, you will see that figure files will be cropped by default if `pdfcrop` is available. You can turn this feature off via:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_crop: false
```